# How to compare time after date?

Tags: sql, date, compare

So I am building a service for selling theatre tickets, when someone wants to buy a ticket the customer will see a list of all available shows.

An available show is defined as follows:

- The show is not sold out
- The date has not been passed
- The time hase not been passed

In the backend there is a query that looks like this to filter only the upcomming shows

```
SELECT * 
FROM shows
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= show.date
```

This query returns the shows of today and the upcomming shows, but it does not filter the shows of today where the start time has been passed. So a customer is still able to buy tickets from a show that has allready started.

I.e: Today is 29th may 2020 and the current time is 21:00:00 the show we are looking at is today and starts at 20:00:00. In the current system it is still possible to buy tickets for this show, but the show allready has started.

Queries like this won't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM shows
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= show.date AND CURRENT_TIME() <= show.time

OR 

SELECT *
FROM shows
WHERE CURRENT_DATE() <= show.date OR CURRENT_TIME() <= show.time
```

These queries wont fit the criteria above because the first query will not return any  show when the time has passed

And the second query doesn't work because it will also return older shows when the time condition matches.

So does anyone have an idea how to write a query that first selects all the shows where the date mathes the codition and the check if the time matches the condition. With respect to the upcomming show.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.  Tag with an appropriate database tag.  Explain how you know if a show is sold out.

Comment: The database management system is phpMyadmin, How I know how a show is sold is: The table is provided is just an example. I use this query as a inner query The show dates and title are stored separately. Because a show can have multiple dates a Customer can reserve many shows, evry show has a location, a location has a capacity. I calculate the amount of reservations for a show on a particular time and check it against the capacity of the show location. That logic seems to be working fine, so that's why I excluded it from the query and posted the part that not working properly and relevant.

Comment: The database management system is phpMyadmin, How I know how a show is sold is: The table is provided is just an example. I use this query as a inner query The show dates and title are stored separately. Because a show can have multiple dates a Customer can reserve many shows, evry show has a location, a location has a capacity. I calculate the amount of reservations for a show on a particular time and check it against the capacity of the show location. That logic seems to be working fine, so that's why I excluded it from the query and posted the part that not working properly and relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is get the tickets that have validity greater than tomorrow's date separately and get the ones of today that match the time condition. So something like this should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM shows
WHERE DateADD(dd,1,CURRENT_DATE()) <= show.date OR (CURRENT_DATE() = show.date AND CURRENT_TIME() <= show.time)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can write : CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) or CONVERT(date,CURRENT_DATE()) like this

SELECT *
FROM shows
WHERE CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) <= shows.date
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM shows
WHERE CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) <= CONVERT(date,shows.date)
```